# Populate object with non-primitive property as String from JSON

Tags: c#, json, exception, converters, populate

I have the following two example classes. Firstly the User class...

```
public class User : ILoadable
{
    public User(string code)
    {
        this.Load(code);
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public UserGroup Group { get; set; }
}
```

... and the UserGroup class.

```
public class UserGroup : ILoadable
{
    public UserGroup(string code)
    {
        this.Load(code);
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    // More properties
}
```

Then I have a method filling the object with data from a json file which is called from the constructors:

```
public static void Load(this ILoadable obj, string code)
{
    string json = GetJsonFromCode(obj.GetType(), code);
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, obj);
}
```

What I want is not to save the User with its complete UserGroup property data, but only with its code, so it can be reconstructed by passing the code to the UserGroup constructor and getting the whole object from there. For example like this:

```
{
    "UserCode": "Admin",
    "Group": "Administrator"
}
```

I already tried creating a JsonConverter and setting it for the Group property with the following code...

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringObjectConverter)]
public UserGroup Group { get; set; }
```

... and converter:

```
class StringObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ILoadable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, new object[] { (string)reader.Value });
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((ILoadable)value).Code);
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to work, because everytime I try to load above seen json, the following exception is thrown:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "Administrator" to type 'MyProject.UserGroup'. Path 'Group', line 2, position 10.'

Inner Exception
ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to MyProject.UserGroup.
```

I could use a little help here, cause I don't know how get this to work, when even the converter does not change anything.

Comment: Also the call of `PopulateObject` does not seem to run into the method `ReadJson` with my UserGroup code/string.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringObjectConverter))]` you must use `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringObjectConverter))]`:

```
public class User : ILoadable
{
    public User(string code)
    {
        this.Load(code);
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringObjectConverter))]
    public UserGroup Group { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) *Instructs the `JsonSerializer` to use the specified `JsonConverter` when serializing the **member** or class.*

  You want to specify a converter to use for the `UserGroup Group` member, so this is the attribute to apply.
- [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) specifies a *`JsonConverter` used when serializing the property's collection items.*

  You would want to apply this attribute if you have a collection, say a `List<UserGroup> Groups`, and need to specify a converter for each item.  Since you don't have a collection, this is not the correct attribute to use.

  (Apparently when an `ItemConverterType` is applied to a member whose value is serialized as a JSON object, Json.NET applies the converter to every member of that object.  This is a bit surprising; I can't find any place this is explicitly documented.  This accounts for the exception you are seeing.)

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UEh27l).